# HTML5 Audio Player - Pause Multiple Audio Elements Except Current Iteration

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I have a working array of audio players, but the problem is that this code allows a user to play multiple tracks at the same time. <strike>I would like to pause all audio players with the exception of the selected audio player, when "play" is clicked.</strike> This was accomplished, but now I can't figure out how to change the affected button images from pause to play. The {{ loop.index }} syntax is twig, and gives each instance of the #play-btn id and the #pause-btn id a unique name ex: #play-btn1 - in case anyone is wondering.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     let play = "#play-btn" + {{ loop.index }};
     let pause = "#pause-btn" + {{ loop.index }};

 $(play).click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
     $(pause).attr( "style", "display: inline-block;" );
      });

 $(pause).click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
     $(play).show();
     }); 
 });

window.addEventListener("play", function(evt) {
    if(window.$_currentlyPlaying && window.$_currentlyPlaying != evt.target){
        window.$_currentlyPlaying.pause();
             } 
        window.$_currentlyPlaying = evt.target;
        }, true);

</script>

<div class="flex justify-center">
  <div class="my-auto">
    <audio id="player{{ loop.index }}" src="{{ block.audio.one.url }}" style="width: 0px;"></audio>
     <a class="play-btn audio-btn" id="play-btn{{ loop.index }}" onclick="document.getElementById('player'+ {{ loop.index }}).play()"></a>
     <a class="pause-btn audio-btn" id="pause-btn{{ loop.index }}" onclick="document.getElementById('player' + {{ loop.index }}).pause()"></a>
                </div>
```